# Post method returns "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.\" after adding authorization on Azure

Tags: asp.net, rest, azure, active-directory

We have created web service which enable to post some data, modify it and send it back all in json format. The entry method has System.Web.Http.HttpPost attribute

```
    [HttpPost]
    public object Index(dynamic input)
    {
     // return modified data;
    }
```

It's work fine but we want to make some automatic test. To make it possible we published site on azure. However to restrict access Azure Active Directory authentication was configured on service.
No changes was made in code. Only Web app/ API application was registered in Active directory with secret key. Then in the service authentication/authorization configuration the client was added.

From code using ADAL library I get access token. Using it I can call get method successfully (service has also another get entry but with different local path)

```
   HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
   result.AccessTokenType, result.AccessToken);
   var uriString = @"http://myService.azurewebsites.net/api/MyGetMethod";
   Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);
   HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
   if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   }
```

But when I am trying to do same with post method I got response :

*{StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed'* with message inside *"{\"Message\":\"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.\"}"*

Below code used to post message:

```
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(result.AccessTokenType, result.AccessToken);
  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
  new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
  var stringContent = new StringContent("{MyData: 5.4}");
  stringContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
  var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://myService.azurewebsites.net/api/MyPostMethod", stringContent).Result;
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
     return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, you have protected the web service with Azure ad and you were able to send the **GET** request successfully.

And from the error message, the issue is relative to the web service. Here is a sample works well for me:

```
// POST api/values
public void Post([FromBody]Message value)
{

}

public class Message
{
     public Double MyData;
}
```

And if the issue still exits, you may share web service code help to narrow down this issue.

### Update

The code sample you upload works well for me no mater authenticate with Azure AD or not , please see the test request below to see whether it is helpful:

[image]

And to integrate the Web API with Azure AD, you can also refer the the code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect.git).

Comment: I cannot reply before, but today I check it again. This time however I added to controller second method with httpGetAttribute. This time service replied but from get method. Although I send post message, azure "redirect" it to get. Locally run service answer by "post" method.

Comment: It is helpful if you can upload a demo project. You can upload it from [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-sg/) and please remove the sensitive information before you uploading.

Comment: I create simple web app. When authentication is off I service returns: "from Post". When authentication of azure is enables I have got:  "Method Get return" The app is at OneDrive:

Comment: link to [OneDrive zipped project](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AijqN97wmsqcbRZHORLGzcr7T0E)